# What impact will a dropping Internet connection have on an in-progress iCloud backup?

Tags: icloud, wifi, backup, iphone

We are in an area where there is extensive construction going on so internet connectivity to our building is frequently interrupted. My iPhone 5 is set to backup to iCloud. I am connected to a local WiFi router in my office for said internet connectivity. If my iPhone 5 is in the middle of an iCloud backup will the backup fail outright and attempt to perform a backup at a later time (when internet connectivity is restored / present) or will it pause and resume when connectivity is restored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iCloud backups are incremental. You'll continue to complete backups when connectivity is restored.